# How to get email of any user from the UID of Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I need to get the email of any user registered in Firebase Authentication from their UID. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using the APIs provided by Firebase Auth web and mobile SDKs (including Flutter).  You would have to either:

- Store data relevant data in a database and perform the lookup there, or
- Implement a backend endpoint that uses the Firebase Admin SDK to [perform the lookup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data)